# Trajectory impact in case of STS hold down studs failure

Tags: space-shuttle, trajectory

The [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34072/saturn-v-and-sts-holding-to-launch-pad-mechanism/34074#comment106250_34074) on this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34072/18825)  made me think, suppose all holding studs mounted on SRBs do get failed, how much impact would it really result in trajectory, considering same fuel burn time of SRBs.

Considering acceleration of $10~m/s^2$ at launch. To calculate the $\delta V$ lost at launch pad.

$$\delta V = 10 \times \delta t$$ where $\delta t$ is time taken by SRBs to break the stud.

I think $\delta t$ can be around 1 second, though I cannot find source to get correct number. If that assumption is correct

$$\delta V = 10~m/s$$ therefore,

Considering total time to orbit as $500~s$
$$\delta S = 10 \times 500 = 5~km$$

Is this a severe trajectory impact? What kind of margins can STS tolerate on trajectory or underperformance and still operate?

Comment: Don't forget the extra 3000 lbs of liquid propellant that the SSMEs burned up sitting on the pad for that extra 1 second.